# Creation of google analytic tracker not giving result for enableAdvertisingIdCollection(true)

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

I am trying to implement Google Analytics. I have tried with the following code , however I am not getting a result for enableAdvertisingCollection on my Google analytics account.

Google suggesting some another code for creation of tracker. I am not getting difference between my code and Google's code. Any one can help me?

My Code:

```
GoogleAnalytics analytics =        GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(getApplicationContext());

Tracker tracker = analytics.newTracker("XXXXXXXXX"); // Send hits to tracker id UA-000-1

    // All subsequent hits will be send with screen name = "main screen"
    tracker.setScreenName("main screen");
    tracker.enableExceptionReporting(true);
    tracker.enableAdvertisingIdCollection(true);
    tracker.enableAutoActivityTracking(true);
    tracker.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder().build());
```

Google Suggesting Code:

```
Tracker t = ((AnalyticsSampleApp) getActivity().getApplication()).getTracker(
        TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
t.enableAdvertisingIdCollection(true);
```

Comment: Have you checked to see if you are getting data in the real-time reports?  Is it an application Google Analytics Account?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

This happens when there is no enough data to display. Google Analytics doesn't want to make users identifiable in some way, so it applies thresholds.
In fact, when you skip the validation, you see this message:

> "Some data in this report may have been removed when a threshold was applied. [Learn more](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2799357?hl=en&utm_id=ad&rd=1#thresholds)"

Just wait for more users to report and you will start to see data.